# The External Libraries missed when Importing a new project into AndroidStudio

Tags: android

There is no enough reputation for me to post a image so I have to describe it by words...

Open the Android Studio and change View from Android to Project there will be 2 child-folders, one is named by your project-name, the other is External Libraries.

There should be SDK and JDK or some support-libraries in it but now nothing!
The problem occured only when I tried to import an exsiting project.

So how to fix it?

Comment: android studio is different from eclipse so u can search and learn

Comment: how do you import this project( like gradle|maven|eclipse project)?

Answer (score 0):

Because, Migrating from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio requires adapting to a new project structure, build system, and IDE functionality. To simplify the migration process, Android Studio provides an import tool so you can quickly transition your Eclipse ADT workspaces and Ant build scripts to Android Studio projects and Gradle-based build files. For your reference check this link, [Migrating to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) Or for steps to do it check this link, [Steps](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html)

Comment: But the project I imported was edited by Android Studio.